# Find the surface charge that appears on a cavity

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, conductors

The problem is of a conducting medium in a uniform field $E_0$. A spherical cavity of radius $a$ is formed inside said medium.

I already found the potential inside and outside the cavity

$\Phi_{\text{int}}=- \frac{3}{2}E_0r\cos(\theta)$

$\Phi_{\text{ext}}= -E_0r\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}E_0a^3\frac{\cos(\theta)}{r^2}$

But I can't find a way to find the surface charge density on the cavity.

It occurs to me to take the value of the potential $\Phi_{\text{int}}$ and calculate the electric field using $E=-\nabla \Phi_{\text{int}}$ and then use Gauss's law to find $\sigma$ but it doesn't work out the result. The book tells me that the result for this density should be

$\sigma=-\frac{3}{2}KE_0\cos(\theta)$

But I don't know who that "$K$" is. I guess it's the dielectric constant which is defined as $K=\epsilon/\epsilon_0$. If it is the dielectric constant, I don't know where to get it from. Can you give me any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, you should use Gauss's law, as you suggest. This is a common/typical homework problem so you should be able to find many examples by googling for things like "surface charge density" and "gauss's law."

Comment: In particular, integrate the maxwell equation $\nabla \cdot E = \rho/\epsilon_0$ over a pill box that has one side in the cavity and one side in the material and you will see how the surface charge is related to the field difference.

Comment: Actually, now I am a little confused, since both your fields seem to have zero radial component at the boundary of the cavity (i.e., $E_r=0$ at $r=a$).

Comment: @hft Sorry, the inner field was missing an $r$. I already modified it

Answer (score 0):

> I already found the potential inside and outside the cavity

> $\Phi_{\text{int}}=- \frac{3}{2}E_0r\cos(\theta)$

> $\Phi_{\text{ext}}= -E_0r\cos(\theta)-\frac{1}{2}E_0a^3\frac{\cos(\theta)}{r^2}$

Integrating $\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E = \rho/\epsilon_0$ over a pillbox (small cylinder) oriented with its long direction along $\hat r$, we find:
$$
\int_{V_{pillbox}}dV \vec \nabla \cdot \vec E = Q_{enc}/\epsilon_0 = \int_{boundary}\vec {dS}\cdot \vec E = \delta S(E_{ext}^r(r=a) - E_{int}^r(r=a))
$$
So, that:
$$
\sigma/\epsilon_0 = -E_{int}^r(r=a)\;,
$$
since $E_{ext}^r(r=a)=0$.

Or:
$$
\sigma = \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \Phi_{int}}{\partial r} = - \frac{3}{2}\epsilon_0E_0\cos(\theta)
$$

---

Another way to approach this problem is to open up your copy of Jackson's "Classical Electrodynamics" (3rd Edition) to page 18 and see that:
$$
(\vec D_2 - \vec D_1)\cdot \hat n = \sigma\;,
$$
but in our case, we have $\vec D_2\cdot\hat n = 0$ at the boundary (per your equations). And we have $-\vec D_1\cdot\hat n = -\epsilon_0E_{int}^r$, since the cavity is empty.

So, again we find:
$$
\sigma = -\epsilon_0E_{int}^r
$$

Comment: Exactly, that's what I find. But in the book, the answer it gives me doesn't have $\epsilon_0$, it has $K$ and that's what has me confused

Comment: Don't know what to tell you. What book are you using?

Comment: I use Reitz Milford's Fundamentals of Electromagnetic Theory. But I'll leave it as you put it. I'm not going to cling to the answer the book gives. It may be wrong. Thank you very much